# htaccess permanent redirect with query string in url

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

how to redirect this page:
example.com/index.php?option=1&view=news
to this
/news

I'm tying simple

```
Redirect /index.php?option=1&view=news /news
```

but it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `mod_rewrite` to match query string:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?option=1&view=news [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /news? [R=301,L]
```